# Basics on loops in python

Tags: python, loops

```
a = "Arun"
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

```
a = "Arun"
for i in a:
   print(i)
```

In both cases, does the loop takes less memory, while the upper code using `print` takes more memory?

While I was studying looping, I got an example from a video as:

> You go to store bring tomato and come home
>
> You again go to store bring cucumber and come home
>
> You again go to store bring onion and come home
>
> This takes more memory
>
> While you can just take a list and bring tomato, cucumber and onion in one go and come to home
>
> This takes up less memory

Can anyone explain it properly?

I thought yeah, creating different variables and printing will take up more storage as if

```
a = "Arun"
b = "Prakash"
print(a)
print(b)
```

But when I thought it in printing each character, then I am a bit confused

```
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

Isn't it just showing the character which are already existing in a variable?

Comment: Imagine your string has one million characters. Do you want to do `print(a[0]) print(a[1]) ... print(a[999999])`?  or just `for i in a: print(i)`?  that's what loops are for, to iterate the elements of anything that is iterable

Comment: You can do break

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is this, both approaches do not differ much in terms of memory, you just have a var a. The code structure so the number of statements executed is different.
The example with the store and list is a diffeent topic. Runtime and Memory usage is highy dependent on the datastructure your using so it doesnt apply much here.

I think best practice is using a loop to access and print each character of a string more efficient and concise compared to writing multiple print statements. However in terms of memory there is not much of a difference. Best wishes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).